# No prevPageToken params on videos list

Tags: youtube-api, google-api

I do this YouTube API call to retrieve the user videos list.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?access_token=secret&part=id,snippet&type=video&forMine=true&maxResults=50&order=date
```

It works great except that it won't return the prevPageToken param.
I know this param is not return on the first page, but my problem here is that it is NEVER returned.

The nextPageToken param works as expected and is always returned.

I tried to remove the order/maxResults params but it did not change anything.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: How many items do you get, in your response ? If at least 2 then, i expect, using maxResults=1, should show a prevPageToken.

Comment: I tested your request example. Same result: NO prevPageToken. I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it should be there. Maybe file it as a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label%3aAPI-YouTube. Check first that it has not been filed already.

I just tried. I do get a prevPageToken for:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=5&pageToken=CAUQAA&q=cover&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

See Response:

```
{
"kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/j02ylGuod7b8YA4wvEAk8TsyYjU\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
 "prevPageToken": "CAUQAQ",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [.....
}
```

And using the value for prevPageToken as pageToken is also working: getting the previous page.

Comment: So the doc is not updated ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#response

Comment: @lou You're right, it should be there, as the documentation says. Then maybe it's a bug. In that case you can use the same link to file this bug. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @lou I just tried. It does work for me. See my updated answer

Comment: So the difference is that you use an API key (key param) while I use an access_token param (from google Oauth). I suspect the bug only comes with this kind of API authentication.

Comment: you're not trying the same call as mine since you also have a q param and do not have the forMine one.

Comment: @lou Yes, there is a difference only in the parameters. I also tested exactly the same url as yours and got the same problem: No prevPageToken in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `setFields` parameter has `prevPageToken` set

```
search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId),nextPageToken,prevPageToken");
```